# Even though I have successfully installed sklearn via Jupyter, I cannot access its classes. What mistake did I make?

Tags: python, class, import, deprecated, sklearn-pandas

Even though I have successfully installed sklearn via Jupyter, I cannot access its classes. What mistake did I make?

```
!pip install sklearn
import sklean
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
      3 label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
      4 # Aplique o LabelEncoder à coluna categórica

ImportError: cannot import name 'LabelEncoder' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (unknown location).
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're encountering is due to a typo in your code.
 You wrote "import sklean" instead of "import sklearn," and that's why you can't access the classes from the `sklearn.preprocessing` module.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually wrote 'import' wrong, but even though I wrote it correctly, the error persists